# C# Drawing on Panels

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi, system.drawing

I'm drawing up a day schedule and representing timeslots with panels, and appointments are yet more panels on top.

The user is able to scroll up and down so that the range they can see is shifted earlier or later. When an appointment runs off the end of the visible range, I want there to be a zig-zag indicating that the appointment extends beyond the visible bounds.

I've identified the case where this occurs, and I call a private function `drawZigZag(Panel p, int direction);` to draw it. The day is spread horizontally, and the direction -1 indicates a zigzag on the left and 1 indicates a zigzag on the right.

So far, I'm not up to the zigzag yet, I'm just experimenting with `CreateGraphics()` and `FillPolygon()`. So far I have:

```
    private void drawZigZag(Panel p, int direction) // 1 = right, -1 = left
    {
        Graphics g = p.CreateGraphics();

        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, Color.Black)), p.DisplayRectangle);

        Point[] points = new Point[4];

        points[0] = new Point(0, 0);
        points[1] = new Point(0, p.Height);
        points[2] = new Point(p.Width, p.Height);
        points[3] = new Point(p.Width, 0);

        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkGreen);

        g.FillPolygon(brush, points);
    }
```

The first `FillRectangle()` I didn't originally have. I only added that when the `FillPolygon()` didn't work.

Basically, it's not working and I'm not sure why. The panel is the original colour - it hasn't been filled DarkGreen. I've used `CreateGraphics()` before for other things, and I'm not really sure why it's not working in this instance. Any ideas?

Edit: Sorry, I thought I should mention: There are several `Label` controls on my `Panel` which describe the appointment. These shouldn't be covered if possible.

Comment: Apologies if I'm completely off the mark here but it doesn't look like you're tying into the invalidation / painting lifecycle of the control.  e.g. subscribing to / overriding the OnPaint event of the control in question etc.

Comment: Remember, your controls will be repainted any time they need to be updated.  So if you try to just paint on your control at some point, it will be repainted back to it's normal look so you won't see your changes.  You need to register your paint method with the Paint event if you'd want to see your changes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to call this method from the paint event handler, not just whenever you like. So in your constructor you might have:

```
panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel1_Paint);
```

and then the implementation:

```
    private void panel1_Paint( object sender, PaintEventArgs e )
    {
        var p = sender as Panel;
        var g = e.Graphics;

        g.FillRectangle( new SolidBrush( Color.FromArgb( 0, Color.Black ) ), p.DisplayRectangle );

        Point[] points = new Point[4];

        points[0] = new Point( 0, 0 );
        points[1] = new Point( 0, p.Height );
        points[2] = new Point( p.Width, p.Height);
        points[3] = new Point( p.Width, 0 );

        Brush brush = new SolidBrush( Color.DarkGreen );

        g.FillPolygon( brush, points );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For example we have this drawing event which is drawing a text from textBox1:

```
private void panel1_draw(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var g = e.Graphics;
        Pen myp = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 4);
        Font fy = new Font("Helvetica", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
        Brush br = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
        g.DrawString(textBox1.Text, fy, br, 0,0);
    }
```

In order to draw on your panel1, you need to write this code in your button event handler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Paint+=new PaintEventHandler(panel1_draw);
        panel1.Refresh();
    }
```

The first line draws the text in your panel and if you want the text to appear you must refresh the panel.
The main thing is in using the panel1.Pain += new PaintEventHandler(your void name); and panel1.Refresh();